# UPDATE Ranks in MySql table that has sub-categories with one statement

Tags: mysql, sql-update, rank

I have a table called times with fields

```
MapID | Type | Style | PlayerID | Time | Points
```

Players (PlayerID) with *lower* times (Time) must have more points than players with *higher* times. Basically, if I had two PlayerIDs: 
PlayerID 3 has time 10.1 seconds and PlayerID 4 has time 10.3 seconds, PlayerID 3 would get 2 points and PlayerID 4 would get 1 point since PlayerID 3's time is worse. If there were 4 PlayerIDs, then the player with the 1st place time would get 4 points and the points would go down by 1 for the next top time. This is all just basically reverse ranks where the top time gets the highest rank in a sense instead of rank 1.

The reason this all has to be in one statement is because in the language I am creating my program in is Sourcepawn which does not allow a delimiter (;) for queries. And the reason I mention sub-categories is that every combination of MapID, Type, Style is it's own sub category.

Here is an image to more easily explain my problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vX6eP.png
I just want to categorize points like that based on MapID, Type, Style, and Time ordered
I did come up with a solution before that worked with SQLite:

```
UPDATE times
SET Points = (
    SELECT t1.Rank
    FROM (
        SELECT t1.id, count(*) AS Rank
        FROM times AS t1, times AS t2
        WHERE t1.MapID=t2.MapID
            AND t1.MapID=%d
            AND t1.Type=t2.Type
            AND t1.Type=%d
            AND t1.Style=t2.Style
            AND t1.Style=%d
            AND t1.Time <= t2.Time
        GROUP BY t1.PlayerID
        ORDER BY t1.Time
    ) AS t1
    WHERE t1.id=times.id
)
WHERE MapID=%d AND Type=%d AND Style=%d
```

Comment: What was the solution with SQLite? I am sure it can be modified to work with MySQL.

Comment: "UPDATE times SET Points=(SELECT t1.Rank FROM (SELECT t1.ROWID, count() AS Rank FROM times AS t1, times AS t2 WHERE t1.MapID=t2.MapID AND t1.MapID=%d AND t1.Type=t2.Type AND t1.Type=%d AND t1.Style=t2.Style AND t1.Style=%d AND t1.Time <= t2.Time GROUP BY t1.PlayerID ORDER BY t1.Time) AS t1 WHERE t1.ROWID=times.ROWID) WHERE MapID=%d AND Type=%d AND Style=%d" It's very bulky but it worked I THINK. I don't like how bulky it is and it requires the same variables multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Add an [`AUTO_INCREMENT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html) column to the table. That column can play the role of the implicit `ROWID` column in the SQLite database.

Comment: Alright, now I have revised it so now every time it says ROWID it says id, and I had to change count() to count(*). Now I am running into an odd problem where the query will only work if I manually issue it directly from the control panel. If I do it through my program, it says: "no such column: t1.id". I am sure it is the one in the 5th line in the query from my first post. But shouldn't that work if I declared times AS t1 in that same statement?

Comment: Then there is a bug in your program or you are using different databases.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem. I was accidentally using the wrong database. I forgot to change the connection method from SQLite to MySQL. Problem solved now then.

Comment: If you accept this answer, others will know that 1) the problem is solved, so there is no need for further assistence 2) an AUTO_INCREMENT column in MySQL is an adequate replacement for the implicit ROWID column in SQLite, so they can try this solution if they encounter a similar problem.